# Cannot set property 'borderColor' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Im copying this from a book (..so it "should" work), i cant get this function to work, it might be a duplicate but i searched for an answer and cant get it working.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'borderColor' of undefined"

It might be something simple but the `to` i believe is the problem i tried setting it to an array and object but i dont really understand,  any solution with simple explanation would be much appreciated.

```js
function changeBorder(element, to){
    element.style.borderColor = to;
}
    
var contentDiv = document.getElementById('color');

contentDiv.onmouseover = function(){
    changeBorder('red');
};
    
contentDiv.onmouseout = function(){
    changeBorder('black');
};
```

```css
.box{
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color:pink;
  padding: 10px;
}
    
.row {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html/js; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row" id="color">
  <div class="element">1</div>
</div>

</body>     
</html>
```

I just want to remove the error message and get the function to do something.

Comment: the function require `element` it should be `changeBorder(this, 'red')`

Comment: changeBorder function has 2 parameter one is DOM and another is color value but you passing only one changeBorder('red').

Comment: thanks @Hanif makes sense..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the **this** and change your functions like this:

```
contentDiv.onmouseover = function(){
    changeBorder(this, 'red');
};

contentDiv.onmouseout = function(){
    changeBorder(this, 'black');
};
```

Without the keyword **this**, it's not going to be found. Remember that in your function you are sharing the **element**:

```
function changeBorder(element, to){
    element.style.borderColor = to;
}
```

Comment: Thanks allot this is working!! Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

Your `changeBorder` method expects 2 arguments but you always call it using only one.

Try this:

```
changeBorder(contentDiv, '[color]');
```

Also, this may not work if the

```
var contentDiv = document.getElementById('color');
```

statement is executed before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `contentDiv` (which may change elsewhere) over `this`?

Comment: @Archer `this` is better but the example call that I've used can be in any context not just inside an event listener's callback function.

Answer (score 0):

changeBorder('red') -> the var element inside the method is set with a string ('red'). A string has not style property, so element.style is undefined and you can't use properties( like borderColor ) of undefined objects

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the code a bit. Please check code below:

```
<html>
  <head>      
     <style>
        .box{
              border: 1px solid red;
              background-color:pink;
              padding: 10px;
            }       
        .row {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
     </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="row" id="color">
        <div class="element">1</div>
   </div>   
   <script type="text/javascript">    
            function changeBorder(element, to){
                element.style.borderColor = to;
            }

            var contentDiv = document.getElementById('color');
            alert(contentDiv);

            contentDiv.onmouseover = function(){
                changeBorder(contentDiv,'red');
            };

            contentDiv.onmouseout = function(){
                changeBorder(contentDiv, 'black');
            };
      </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```